# The smoke domain is completely filled with smoke

Tags: materials, modifiers, eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, render-layers

The domain is filled with smoke before the simulation started.

[image: smoke domain]

Answer (score 3):

That is normal. As long as there is no simulated smoke, the complete volume of the domain is filled with the volumetric material.

Comment: so what should I do

Comment: Simulate the smoke. Each frame you want to render has to be simulated or you have to make the domain invisible for those frames that don't have a simulation.

Comment: But why is it so. Its a lil bit annoying, when you wanna render a OpenVDB sequence and the first and last frame somehow has this filled box data, these files are also much bigger.

I had to set the simulation from 0 to 36 and then delete in files the 0 and the 36th to get it without. 

Thats a lil bit tedious actually...

Comment: @Gordon1fm Well, what OpenVDB sequence are you talking about? My answer was about the Mantaflow smoke domain. When I properly simulate smoke there, I do not get a first and last frame "somehow filled" with box data. If you talk about an imported sequence from somewhere else, how should I know where it got the "somehow filled" data from? It's very unclear what you mean and apart from that are the answers section and the comments not supposed to be used for discussing new problems. You should ask a new question for that as it seems to be a different topic.

Comment: Excuse me, if I hadn't specified enough. It has to do with this topic!
So I made a Smoke simulation in blender and baked with 35frames. So I can use this VDB sequence from cache in another scene, to also reduce calculations there. But somehow, it has filled first and last frame with these full domain. Although the simulation starts at frame 1 and ends at frame 35.
Idk, if this is a bug with mantaflow and can be fixed.
Otherwise I still had to expand the sequence to 0 - 36 and delete first/last. Or deactivate in renders or set density to 0 before.
Question was actually just: Is this a bug?

Comment: @Gordon1fm As I said before, you baked and it is somehow filled in the first and last frame is not enough information. When I do it, it does not happen. But to decide if it is a bug or you are doing something wrong, we need more information on what you are doing. And this question was about an unbaked simulation. Yours is different and therefore, again, **the answers section and the comments (are) not supposed to be used for discussing new problems. You should ask a new question for that**!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I`m sorry, now I've opened the Scene files and have tried to reproduce and it actually works. But in the huge scene I have some special case with a material with Ambient Occlusion shader behind the Volume, that adds dark shadows. If I deactivate AO node or as said delete these first/last VDB files, its fine. And I Can't reproduce it in another file, with same VDB sequence Volume and Materials and Lights and so on. That's why I actually hadn't opened a new topic, because I didn't rly know what to ask, just find out it has something to do with these filled domain. Nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I solved it by keyframing the density in the Domain's material settings to 0 before the start of the frame and then to the density I wanted at the start of the simulation.